# ng-class is called too many times

Tags: angularjs

I am quite new to AngularJS and I'm developing a full featured audio player à la Google Music. I have a Player service that deals with all the playing, queueing, etc. I have an infinite scrolling table with all the tasks, and I need to apply a certain class on that track that is now playing.

The first angular way I can think of doing this would be using something like the following:

```
ng-class="{ playing: player.getCurrent()._id == song._id}"
```

on every single row. If the id of the song matches the one the player is well, playing, then it will have a different color. The thing is that since there are that many rows in the table, the expression would need to be evaluated on every single case. On jQuery this would be as simple as:

```
$('td[data-songid="'+playingId+'"]).addClass("playing").siblings(".playing").removeClass("playing");
```

What would be the angular, effecive way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are (almost) always free to wrap your jQuery in directive:

In view:

```
<table song-highlight>
  <tr ng-repeat="s in songs" data-songid="{{s.id}}">
   <td>...</td> 
  </tr>
</table>
```

In JS:

```
app.directive('songHighlight', function(){
  return function($scope, $element, $attrs){
    $scope.$watch('playingId', function(playingId){
      $element.find('tr').removeClass('playing');
      $element.find('tr[data-songid="' + playingId + '"]').addClass('playing');
    })
  };
});
```

[Demo plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/W9kMeVlFbpjYnd7cLm8d?p=preview)

Comment: In the [AngularJS FAQ](http://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) they suggest that you stop using jQuery to modify the DOM in controllers. I think I finally see the light here... It's ok to use jQuery for tasks like this **in directives** but just not out right in my controller code? I was just trying to avoid it all together.

Comment: Yes, forget the DOM while you're in the controller. Controllers shouldn't even be aware that there's a DOM sitting next to them. Deal with the DOM only through the directives, but even there, try not to expand you DOM scanning to far away from the directive element (try not to use $.find() outside of $element closest ancestors and descendants).

Comment: So what if I am playing a song that still doesn't appear on the list due to infinite scroll? When it appears on list it won't be highlighted because the directive only listens to changes on the scope variable, right? Do I need to duplicate this functionality on the view too?

Comment: In that case you could for example broadcast an event (`$scope.$broadcast('list_reloaded')`) when infinite scroll handler loads new items, and, in the same directive (`songHighlight`) listen for that event with `$scope.$on('list_reloaded', highlightItem)`. In this case, the `highlightItem` would be a function siting inside the `songHighlight` directive, which encapsulates the jQuery block for removing adding class name. So in the end, you would be calling this `highlightItem` function on two separate occasions: When `playingId` is changed and when infinite scroll loads new items.